# Database design for entering comments to a dashboard with data being refreshed daily

Tags: database-design, azure-sql-database, refresh, dashboard, data-ingestion

I want to create a dashboard with a table which has list of stocks and metrics related to them. I want to have a "Comment" column in this table where I will be entering the comments for each stock after reviewing metrics related to them. The metrics related data will be refreshed daily, however I want the comments entered previously to stay as it is. What would be the best way to design the tables for this usecase? I am planning to use Azure sql database for this.

I am not sure where to start as of yet.

Comment: Wikipedia has an article about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 0):

I found the exact [example](https://exceltown.com/en/tutorials/power-bi/powerbi-com-and-power-bi-desktop/power-bi-charts-and-visualization/power-bi-adding-comments-in-visuals/) for you:

1. Pull your data [from internet](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/82689/api-for-commodities-stock-markets) and create a stock market dashboard
2. Create a table in Excel or Google Docs where you will store the comments
3. Link the two using the stock code as a link

Done.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this solution